# Can I publish an Azure Worker Role ... but it doesn't auto-start?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I wish to put up some workers roles (cloud services) to the staging section/configuration.

Can i publish them to there, but not get them to auto-start?

once they are up. I can manually stop the production one, manually start the staging one and test.

I don't want both running that the same time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is certainly possible.

If you're deploying your services through **PowerShell** using [`New-Deployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn495143.aspx) Cmdlet, you can specify for the role to not start automatically by specifying `-DoNotStart` switch parameter.

If you're deploying your services through **Visual Studio**, I don't think this option is available.

If you're deploying your services through [`Create Deployment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460813.aspx) **REST API** directly, you can specify for the role to not start by setting value of `<StartDeployment>` element to `false`.

If you're deploying you services through **Windows Azure Portal**, you can specify for the role to not start by un checking the checkbox labeled `Start deployment` as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! *Unfortunately* I deploy with Visual Studio .. so it looks like I'm out of luck. Never-the-less, you have answered the question. Cheers! (and a bitter sweet answer, it is).